# Which deities should not be worshiped in the house and why?

Tags: gods, worship, goddess

Are there any gods or goddess who should not be worshiped in the house? And for what reason they should not be worshiped?

Comment: There is a belief in my place (Bengal) that God Saturn or Shani Dev should not be worshiped inside a house and that's why  he is worshiped either in the temples and if it has to be in the house, then they do it on the roof terrace.

Comment: I am sorry, I want to add this comment only, but do not have sufficient points to add a comment. They say Vastu purusha should not be worshiped in households. Also one needs guru's guidance in worshiping dasamahavidyas. Also although there is no restriction in worshiping other deities, statues of them taller than 8" should not be kept at home. Hope this helps.